# Ubuntu 20.04 host running VBox - Win 10 guest - Multiple "ALSA Plug-in [VirtualBoxVM]" lines in Sound Settings - Causes sound to fail

Tags: sound, virtualbox, pulseaudio, alsa

So I have sound working 100% in Ubuntu for all apps until I start up any of my guest VirtualBox machines (happen to all be Windows 10 guests but suspect that's irrelevant).

When I start the VirtualBox guest, in my host's Sound settings I start seeing multiple "ALSA Plug-in [VirtualBoxVM]" entries like so:

[image]

As you can see, there are 11 lines of the ALSO plug-in...  but not sure why.  Now that picture above is the first 5 minutes after starting the guest... but if I leave it running, more and more entries keep showing up of this ALSA Plug-in:

[image]

...and after a few more minutes, you can't even see them all in 1 screenshot...

So, after some number of these show up, my sound in the Ubuntu host completely stops working.  I have not found a pattern to the number of them that causes other apps not to play audio though.   It's in the 30+ entries though...

If try to open a video in YouTube for example, it shows me a message saying I should restart my audio:  "Audio Renderer error.  Please restart your computer" - now just force-reload of ALSA fixes it for a few minutes but eventually the ALSA Plug-in loads enough of them to break it again...  and if I don't run the VirtualBox instances, none of this happens.

EDIT:   I can't find anything on this and I really can't believe I'm the only one seeing this.   I think it's 100% a VirtualBox conflict/issue but nothing in DMESG or anywhere showing there's an actual problem...  it just can't play any more audio streams as all these ones are taken up in VBox

[image]

Edit 2:   I had a work around that worked for a few days but now that too fails...  and that seems to rule out the ROG motherboard as the issue... the work around was I found my HDMI monitor had an audio out plug, moved my speaker/amp to that, and I got audio with that sound 'card' selected....  so it went from my PC to my monitor, monitor converted to analog and played sound to the speakers.    Well after a few days this too is having the same issue -  BUT it worked great for a few days.

Again, no DMESG errors indicating the issue, nothing that seems to have 'filled up' any logs but after a few days this stopped working...

Really plagued by this issue, restarting audio with "pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload"...  for maybe 30 min to an hour - or persistently if continually playing audio, but if audio stops, it will stop working after 30 or so minutes until I restart pulse/alsa again.

EDIT 3:

I have a terrible workaround.... changing the VirtualBox settings for the guest from using the Alsa host driver to PulseAudio prevented all the extra ALSA plug-in entries but the audio is choppy... at least you can hear something so it's good for notifications but not good audio.... setting back to ALSA brings the problem back again.   I still really need a permanent fix but this at least shows it's a problem in the ALSA / AC97 drivers with VirtualBox since it doesn't happen with the Pulse ones.

[image]

[image]